# IPFS: HTTPError: URL arg must be multibase encoded: selected encoding not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, ipfs-http-client, orbitdb

I want to create an [OrbitDB database with a locally running IPFS daemon](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db#module-with-ipfs-daemon).

My code is based on a [code sample published in a past discussion](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/issues/789), with a few changes.

Here is my code (test.js):

```
import * as IpfsClient from 'ipfs-http-client'
import OrbitDB from 'orbit-db'

const ipfs = IpfsClient.create('/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001')

const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs)

const db = await orbitdb.eventlog('mydatabase')
```

I started the IPFS daemon by `ipfs daemon`.

When I run my code with `node test.js`, it fails on the last line. I am getting the following error:

```
/home/me/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/lib/core.js:100
  let error = new HTTP.HTTPError(response)
              ^

HTTPError: URL arg must be multibase encoded: selected encoding not supported
    at Object.errorHandler [as handleError] (/home/me/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/lib/core.js:100:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.fetch (/home/me/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/node_modules/ipfs-utils/src/http.js:145:9) {
  response: Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
      body: PassThrough {
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          flowing: true,
          ended: true,
          endEmitted: true,
          reading: false,
          constructed: true,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: false,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: true,
          autoDestroy: true,
          destroyed: true,
          errored: null,
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: false,
          dataEmitted: true,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
          error: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ],
          data: [Function (anonymous)],
          end: [Function (anonymous)]
        },
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          finalCalled: true,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: true,
          ended: true,
          finished: true,
          destroyed: true,
          decodeStrings: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 0,
          writing: false,
          corked: 0,
          sync: false,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writecb: null,
          writelen: 0,
          afterWriteTickInfo: null,
          buffered: [],
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          allBuffers: true,
          allNoop: true,
          pendingcb: 0,
          constructed: true,
          prefinished: true,
          errorEmitted: false,
          emitClose: true,
          autoDestroy: true,
          errored: null,
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
        },
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
      },
      disturbed: true,
      error: null
    },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/pubsub/sub?arg=%2Forbitdb%2F.............%2Fmydatabase',
      status: 500,
      statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
      headers: Headers {
        [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
          'access-control-allow-headers': [ 'X-Stream-Output, X-Chunked-Output, X-Content-Length' ],
          'access-control-expose-headers': [ 'X-Stream-Output, X-Chunked-Output, X-Content-Length' ],
          'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
          server: [ 'kubo/0.16.0' ],
          trailer: [ 'X-Stream-Error' ],
          vary: [ 'Origin' ],
          date: [ 'Thu, 01 May 2023 01:00:00 GMT' ],
          'transfer-encoding': [ 'chunked' ]
        }
      },
      counter: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure, but it seems to me that the IPFS daemon does not allow me to create a database (or generally a file). What is missing here? How can I solve this problem?